# Merge Two Aarrys

Tags: php

I have two arrays one is the superset of other,how to create a third array which has all the values of both arryas but not repeating
     me please

```
$a = array(1,2,3);
$b = array(1,2,3,4);
```

output must be like this

```
$c = array(1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: use array_merge and array_unique for correct output

Comment: You are expected to make some effort of your own before posting.

Comment: @Nigel Ram..yes..i have tried many Array function like in_array,array_merge etc..but don't get the required result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [array_merge()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) along with [array_unique()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
array_unique(array_merge($a,$b));
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/lfm1b

***Note:-*** if you want to re-index array use `array_values()` [added in my working example link]

Reference:

[array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$c = array_unique(array_merge($a, $b));
```

All of this can be seen in: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_merge` with `array_unique`

```
print_r(array_unique(array_merge($a,$b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` sign to merge them

```
$c = $a + $b;
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/5P2LP